# Exchange Online send limits via Outlook client and MAPI

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, office365

The send limits for Exchange Online are detailed [here.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/exchange-online-service-description/exchange-online-limits#receiving-and-sending-limits)

At the time of writing that's 30 messages\minute via SMTP and there are limits on the number of recipients also.

My question is - when sending emails through the Outlook desktop client using MAPI 2.0, do the limits still apply or is throttling applied somewhere in the process so that basically any number of mails could be pumped through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this blog: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2011/06/23/exchange-online-throttling-and-limits-faq/

According it, the following settings are common to MAPI and EWS clients.

MessageRateLimit – Identifies the maximum number of messages that can be sent per minute. This is configured to count sent messages on a per IP address basis.

RecipientRateLimit – Identifies the maximum number of recipients that a sender can send to in a 24-hour period.

ForwardeeLimit – Identifies the maximum number of recipients that can be configured for Inbox rules when the user account is using the forward or redirect action.